# Determine if a set of integers is "mirrorable" into another set of same length without bruteforce calculation

Tags: linear-transformations

Assume there are two sets of integers (with a "set" being an unordered collection of elements without duplicates).
Both sets have an equal length >= 1.

Example of two sets with length 3:
$$
set_a = \{1, 4, 8\}
$$
and
$$
set_b = \{-2, 2, 5\}
$$

Those two specific sets are transformable into one another by "mirroring" each of their items $x$ at $m=3$. (Note that although the elements are integers, this $m$ is not necessarily an integer but could also be rational).

```
                m              
-2 -1 ±0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8
 .  .  .  .  .  |  .  .  .  .  . 
 .  .  .  a  .  |  a     .  .  a
 b  .  .  .  b  |  .  b  .  .  .
 .  .  .  x-----|---->y  .  .  .
 y<-------------|--------------x
 .  .  .  .  y<-|--x  .  .  .  .
```

The transformation rule for mirroring any element $x_n$ at $m$ into the new element $y_n$ is
$$
x ➡ y = m+(m-x) = 2m-x
$$
$$
1 ➡ 3+(3-1) = 5\\
4 ➡ 3+(3-4) = 2\\
8 ➡ 3+(3-8) = -2\\
$$

I want to find out, if for any two given sets of equal length there exists a constant $m$ which fulfills the mirroring condition.

If it weren't sets but vectors (with ordered elements), then I could check if $m$ is the same
$$
\frac{y_i+x_i}{2} = m_i\overset{!}{=} m_j = \frac{y_j+x_j}{2}
$$
for all $i$,$j$.

But if the order is not important: How do I check if there is a mirror $m$ that fulfills the condition?

I'm looking for a "smart" property of both sets which I could compare to check if there is a potential mirror (e.g. if the property has the same value for both sets). I don't want to bruteforce all possible combinations.

I'm sure there is a concept behind this kind of problem, but it's been a while since I last attended a lecture.

Answer (score 2):

If you order the elements of the vector from largest to smallest, then its mirror will have the opposite order, from smallest to largest, such that:

If there are $N$ elements, then all the sums $x_i + y_{N-i+1}$ are the same to $2m$ iff the set is mirrorable. Here, the index $i$ runs from $1$ to $N$.